# How to get Enum type name in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have below enum in Typescript

```
export enum Color {
  // ... values 
}
```

How can I get enum type name ie `Color`

I tried `(typeof Color).toString()` but it results `object`

### Why do I need this

I want to create a service in angular called `LookupService` which will have a method to pass `Color` as type or as generic parameter of function and will return array of value and translated text of each value of enum.

I can pass string, but I want to use the power of typescript to make it typed and prevent typos

my function will be like

```
getLookup<E>(): Array<{key: E, text: string}> 
{
    const result = mybackend.query(name of E);
    return result
}
```

and usage will be like below

```
this.lookupService.get(Color);
this.lookupService.get<Color>();
```

Comment: An enum compiles to a simple JS object. The only "name" it has is the variable it's assigned to. You can't really reverse look this up. What are you trying to do, since this sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: bit of a hack, but maybe something like `console.log(Object.keys({Color})[0]);` ?

Comment: @NickParsons wouldn't this just give you the enum values? Or maybe keys - I can't remember which order they'd be generated in.

Comment: @NickParsons I liked the hack, creating an object and getting first key of that object ;)

Comment: @VLAZ he created an object with one key which is Color

Comment: @Reza yeah, I was not thinking properly. But if you already known that `Color` is the variable you want, then the entire creation of an object is pointless - you can already just do `"Color"`, since you know that's the name. You don't need to use the variable to generate the name.

Comment: @VLAZ If I use string, it's not type safe, Nick solution is type safe, and no typo will happen

Comment: @Reza let's get back to *why* do you need to have a type safe name of a variable? What are you doing to generate the name of a variable and make sure it's not misspelled? Because normally you should be using `Color.RED`, etc. - the TS compiler will catch if you misspell it, as, say, `Colour.RED`. Using the *string* `"Color"` sounds wrong.

Comment: @VLAZ I want to create a lookup service in angular to pass an enum, and then that service query backend to return values + translated text

Comment: @NickParsons do you know any hacks to make it generic, something like `getEnumTypeName<E>(): string {
  return Object.keys({ E: E })[0];
 }` I get `'E' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here` error

Comment: I also don't understand how having a string `"Color"` will help you do anything with the variable named `"Color"` unless you use something like `eval()` or use a property accessor on `globalThis`/`window`. Is that your plan?  If so, it would be better to just make some object like `const enums = { Color, ... }` and then `enums.Color` will be a safer way to access it (and then you can see how the string name is not really important, as `const enums = {color: Color}` works just as well with `enums.color`.

Comment: @jcalz see my updated question

Comment: @jcalz using enums.Color is not Open/Closed

Comment: ...I wouldn't try to look up the name at all, I'd just initialise the `enum` with a value, e.g., `enum Color { RED = 'color-red', GREEN = 'color-green'}` and then just send `Color.RED` which will resolve to `"color-red"` or whatever you make the value. Sure, it's *slightly* more typing but afterwards it's type safe and will save you headaches down the road.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't want to call  the function per enum item, I will get the list to show in a drop down

Comment: @Reza Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Sprotty no I didn't

Comment: I have the exact same use-case of fetching translated enum values to show in a selectbox. The best I can do is make the selectbox typed as string, but this is not type safe and cannot be affected to the proper enum. Annoying...